# White line on left of ubuntu Launcher when desktop icons enabled

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, 17.04

So there seems to be this strange white line on the left side of the unity launcher that only appears when desktop icons are enabled.

[image: Thin White Line On Left Of Screen]

I have not been able to find much about this issue. I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the Paper theme, the question is answered here:

https://github.com/snwh/paper-gtk-theme/issues/318

I changed the line:

```
border-left-width: 1px;
```

to:

```
border-left-width: 0px;
```

Reloaded the Paper theme and sorted :)